# Apply changed limits in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I changed the limits (default requested amount of CPU) on my Kubernetes cluster. Of course the new limits  don't affect already running Pods. So, how can I apply the new (lower) limits to already running Pods.

1. Is there any way to update the limits in the running Pods without restarting them?
2. If I have to restart the Pods, how can this be done without deleting and recreating them? (I am really using pure Pods, no Depoyments or so)

Comment: You cant change the properties of a running pod. It would reject the changes. 
Rather you can create a deployment whose rolling update feature ensures, one pod will be running during the update of limits.

Answer (score 5):

You need to restart the Pods:

1. You can't update the `resources` field of a running Pod. The update would be rejected.
2. You need to create new Pods and delete the old ones. You can create the new ones first and delete the old ones when the new ones are running, if this allows you to avoid downtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that only when you run it as a deployment, or atleast run a pod with `RestartPolicy` as `RestartAlways`, so you can always scale down to zero and scale up to 1 for a safe restart. 
  
In your case, considering that you just run your pod using `kubectl` run without any `restartpolicy`, or a `restartpolicy` as Never, i would run another pod, test and kill the already running ones. 
  
Expect better answers from any one.

Answer (score 0):

You cant change the properties of a running pod. It would reject the changes. Rather you can create a `deployment` whose `rolling update` feature ensures,

one pod will be running during the update of limits.
There wont be any downtime for your pod.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the resource and limit of running Pod directly.
So You first need to replicate your YAML file to a new file

cmd: kubectl get pod  -o yaml > New.yaml

Then, you make changes to the resource and limit in the New.yaml file, Then apply this yaml file.

cmd: kubectl replace -f New.yaml --force